# iOS: Tableview, how to end edit correctly?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an (embedded) tableview in my view. Each cell has a button to change the cell image and a textfield which text can be changed during edit.

At the moment I have these three end edits after pressing the done button:

```
    [super setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    //resigns first responder for all textfields
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
```

1. are they all necessary?
2. Problem with [self.view endEditing:YES] is, that it ends the edit state without animation. So the edited cell is immediately "pushed" back into non editing mode, whereas the other cells slowly move back (as it should be). Trying to anmitate this line didn't help. Leaving it completely out works look-wise (transitions are smooth again), however the keyboard doesn't get hidden and the keyboard cursor is still blinking in the last active table cell. What can I do here?

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot make a screenshot of this behaviour, since it's happenning too fast. The currently active cell is just immediately in its original position, as well as (!) slowly moving back from the edit indented state..I mean normally the cells get indented during edit right. I've tried to comment a lot of lines in my code that could cause this behaviour but nothing happened. Except when I comment out this self.view endEditing:YES line.

Comment: You are using [self.view endEditing:YES]; Which looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for the text field that is currently the first responder. If it finds one, it asks that text field to resign as first responder...Why don't resign the first responder only for the active textField?

Comment: Thx I've been looking now at a very other location and found the problem. Probably need to start a new thread for that. Obviously the problem is with my core data view controller not with the table view...but thx for your hints